# Is it true that a word that consists of two adjective words has a neutral tone on the second word?

Tags: word-choice, word, word-requests

Do the words, such as 冰凉冰凉, 雪白雪白, and 通红通红, each have a netural tone on the second word?

e.g. 漂漂亮亮 [piào piao lìang lìang]

Comment: see comments ＃２，３ of 
https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/26231/how-can-i-tell-apart-which-two-syllable-adjective-forms-abab-to-emphasize-it   esp。在口语中第二个音节可念轻声，第三音节念‌​第一声，第四音节也念第一声，儿化并且是重‌​音所在。如＂漂漂亮亮＂／piàopiao liāng liāngr  。。。。

Comment: I can't read Chinese. Please translate it into English!

Comment: Please!!!!!!!!!

Comment: You ask about ABAB pattern words then give an AABB example...

Comment: this article https://wenku.baidu.com/view/0bacec06524de518974b7d5e.html here says: ⑸

 

“

ABAB

”形式的动词重叠词中的“

B

”都读轻声。如：研究研究（

jiu

）

(jiu)

Comment: ABAB verbs will be neutral toned on the B

Comment: But, Jacob said it's not.

Comment: @user3306356 Only AABB has a neutral tone?

Comment: Can't ABAB have a neutral tone?

Comment: I've already given you ABAB examples, such as 冰凉冰凉

Comment: And, what is the erhua as in 漂漂亮亮儿?

Comment: translation:colloquial type: ＂漂漂亮亮＂／piàopiao liāng liāngr ／＂明明白白＂／míngming bāi bāir ／formal/regular type:＂漂漂亮亮＂ ／piàopiao liàng liàng／＂明明白白＂／ míngming bái bái／

Comment: What about＂漂漂亮亮＂piàopiao liāng liāng without erhua?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think so.

冰凉冰凉, 雪白雪白, and 通红通红 might or might not have neutral tones.

漂漂亮亮 often have neutral tones, but loot at 浑浑噩噩.

I think neutral tone is a phenomenon in speaking, words like 浑浑噩噩 that is not often used in speaking don't have neural tone.

Note, I did not say they have or they don't have,  it depends on your tone of voice. If people want to be clear or serious, they don't use neutral tone. If they want to be lazy or natural, they use neutral tone.

There are no strict rules.

If you want to use neutral tone, it will be the B in ABAB and AABB. Since neutral tone always on the last character of a word.