# Where should I put a neutral tone in 雪白雪白?

Tags: word-choice, word, word-requests

雪白雪白 
(1) xuě-bai-xuě-bái (such as 漂漂亮亮)
(2) xuě-bái-xuě-bai

If ABB and AAB adjectives also have neutral tones, please let me know where tones should be.

Comment: No, you should not use neutral tone in this word. Use the (2) version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all words apply neutral tone.

雪白雪白: xuě-bái-xuě-bái

漂漂亮亮: piào piào liang liang

You see in 漂亮, 亮 is a neutral tone, while 白 is the second tone in 雪白.

Checking in dictionaries is a good way to make sure you apply neutral tone correctly.

Comment: But, dictionaries don't have any correct answer.

Comment: They do. you could look up 雪白 and 漂亮.

Comment: http://www.zdic.net/sousuo/ No they don't

Comment: see this: http://www.zdic.net/c/a/fb/262820.htm and http://www.zdic.net/c/2/22/52124.htm

Comment: It doesn't show any neutral sound when a adjective is reduplicated!!!!

Comment: I don't think the duplication of adjectives would change the tone. Do you have any specific example for it?

Comment: see comments ＃２，３ of 
https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/26231/how-can-i-tell-apart-which-two-syllable-adjective-forms-abab-to-emphasize-it   esp。在口语中第二个音节可念轻声，第三音节念‌​第一声，第四音节也念第一声，儿化并且是重‌​音所在。如＂漂漂亮亮＂／piàopiao liāng liāngr  。。。。

Comment: It might be ok in spoken in that case, but if you put that way in exams, that would be considered to be wrong.

Comment: So, still the best way to make sure you get it right is to look up a dictionary.

Comment: When you pronunciate piao piao liang liang, you speak liang in a neutral tone as Chinese?

Comment: I would probably go like a normal one as it in a dictionary:piào piào liang liang . The thing is when you speak fast, the second piào might sound like something between piao and piào. But indeed, I think the correct pronunciation should be piào.

Comment: When I pronounce 漂漂亮亮 I say piào piào liàng liàng (all 4th tone)